# pam_open_session: System error and sudo: policy plugin failed session initialization with no pass expiary in etc/pam.d/password-auth

Tags: rhel, rhel7, pam

I am struggeling with an error in REHL 7.
I have a REHL Image witch is accessible only over SSH key without user/password credentials.

To prevent the password renew process after 90 days (which is not possible with SSH key) I added the no_pass_expiry in my etc/pam.d/password-auth

but then i receive the following error when i try to sudo

```
pam.d]$ sudo su -
sudo: pam_open_session: System error
sudo: policy plugin failed session initialization
```

this only occures after the 90 day.

Answer (score 7):

Your password is probably expired. for example... here's sudo with an expired user:

```
[user@server ~]$ sudo whoami
sudo: pam_open_session: System error
sudo: policy plugin failed session initialization
[user@server ~]$ 

[user@server ~]$ chage -l user
Last password change                    : May 07, 2018
Password expires                    : Aug 05, 2018
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 1
Maximum number of days between password change      : 90
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 10
```

Now, as shown,  after reseting the expiration flag, sudo works as expected:

```
[root@server]# chage -m 0 -M 99999 -I -1 -E -1 user
[root@server]# chage -l user
Last password change                    : May 07, 2018
Password expires                    : never
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 10

[user@server ~]$ sudo whoami
root
```

You can confirm that on `/var/log/secure` by checking for similar messages as the ones listed below:

```
Feb 27 16:59:14 server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:account): expired password for user user (password aged)
Feb 27 16:59:14 server sudo: user : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=anotheruser ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/whoami
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure if **SELinux** is enforcing, that `/etc/shadow` has the right context label. Running `restorecon /etc/shadow` will remedy this.